# JavaScript variable scope

Tags: javascript, variables, scope, global

Here's my code

```
errors=0;
$(document).ready(function () {
    var chk=$("#usnm").val();
    $.post("register.php",{'chkuser':chk},function(data){
        if(data==" Username already exists.Choose a new one"){
            errors++;
            alert(errors);
            $("#alerts").html(data);
        }
     });
     if(errors==0){
         alert(errors+"post");
     }
});
```

Here, the first alert gives me a "1" whereas the second alert runs, so therefore it give me '0post'   . What i'd like to know is: How is the value of the variable errors, changing to 0 all of a sudden after being 1 ?

Thanks

Comment: is it because the flow of control moves onto the next function before $.post() can respond ?

Comment: There is a space before " Username already exists...". Is that a mistake?

Comment: @danialentzry : No that was intentional. And the issue was timme lag. Thanks anyways :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `errors=0;` to `var errors=0;`

and put the error check inside the `$.post` function:

```
   $.post("register.php",{'chkuser':chk},function(data){
        if(data==" Username already exists.Choose a new one"){
            errors++;
            alert(errors);
            $("#alerts").html(data);
        }
        if(errors==0){
            alert(errors+"post");
        }
     });
```

Comment: tried that, doesn't work, However, the time lag issue , when corrected, seemed to make it work.

Thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

jquery.post is called asynchronously. you might be debugging it locally otherwise the second alert would go on the first place. anyways because it runs async the value is different inside and outside the post function